# Android WebView: weird rendering of 1px lines on hdpi screens

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a WebView that displays some generated HTML. The content includes a list and the list item CSS includes `border-top: 1px`.

On hdpi devices the WebView tries to scale this line 1.5x. Sometimes the lines render as *1 real pixel* and sometimes they render as *2 real pixels*. In fact, it seems to pick 1 or 2 pixels alternately.

I'm specifically looking for a solution that doesn't involve `<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />`. I *do* want the WebView to handle scaling as long as 1px lines are rendered consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution is the one you don't want to hear: don't scale the WebView content, but fix it with CSS. You might have some luck using em's in stead of px in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using border, use box-shadow inset with 1px, like this:

```
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #000000;
 box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #000000;
```